# how to create combination unique key constrain in GreenDAO

Tags: android, unique-constraint, greendao

I want to create a table in where combination two column values wont repeat.

```
 Entity entity = schema.addEntity("TableName");
    entity.addLongProperty("id").primaryKey().autoincrement();
    entity.addStringProperty("firstId");
    entity.addStringProperty("secondId");
```

Here i want to create a unique key for firstId & secondId 
`Index indexUnique = new Index();
        indexUnique.addProperty(firstId);
        indexUnique.addProperty(secondId);
        indexUnique.makeUnique();`

tried adding index unique . but this makes both property as unique. but not the combination unique.. that i want.

Answer (score 2):

The [documentation](http://greenrobot.org/greendao/documentation/modelling-entities/#Properties_and_primary_keys) says:

> Current primary key (PK) restrictions: Currently, entities must have a long or Long property as their primary key. This is recommended practice for Android and SQLite. greenDAO is prepared to handle any primary key scenario in the future, but not everything is implemented completely yet. ***To work around this issue, you can use a long primary key and use an unique index for the intended “key” properties.***

For you:

```
Entity entity = schema.addEntity("TableName");
entity.addIdProperty().primaryKey().autoincrement();
Property firstIdForTableNamePK = entity.addStringProperty("firstId").notNull().getProperty();
Property secondIdForTableNamePK = entity.addStringProperty("secondId").notNull().getProperty();
Index indexUnique = new Index();
indexUnique.addProperty(firstIdForTableNamePK);
indexUnique.addProperty(secondIdForTableNamePK);
indexUnique.makeUnique();
entity.addIndex(indexUnique);
```